# Determine whether the given set S is a subspace of the vector space V.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine whether the given set S is a subspace of the vector space V.
>   [image]

I think it is C,D, and F but I am wrong unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subsets that ares subspaces of the indicated space are: A, C, D, E

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/663290)

Comment: The question, as posed, is to provide the correct answers for series of quizz-like questions. It does not ask for explanations.

Comment: The blog policy for comments is "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." \\ I did not have any questions for author, nor I needed a clarification, and to the best of my understanding I answer the question.

Comment: @VictorZurkowski Ignore them lol

Comment: @Yusha Last week I tried to add a comment to an answer, but I couldn't because I did not have enough reputation points, so I added my comment as an answer. An editor deleted my answer telling me to go get more points and come back when I can comment. I've been franctically collecting points so I can go back to the question, repost my comment, and spite the editor. I am very sensitive about the distinction between comment and answer because I am on a mission (don't lol too hard... :) )

Comment: @VictorZurkowski Thank you for your help, I needed the solution so that I could figure out **why** those selection were true, thanks to you. I could google the selections and figure out what's going on. I would ignore most of the people on here, they are truly very rude and just want a reason to complain. Thanks again!

Comment: @Yusha Thanks. If you have question on why the answers are as they are, let us know.